# passing schema name as parameter in native query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the below two queries which run on different schema altogether 
below are the queries:

```
select abccode from abc_first.table_configurations_name;

select abccode from abc_sec.table_configurations_name;
```

for the first query the schema is `abc_first` and the for the second query the schema is `abc_sec` now I have to write the parameterized query in JPA whereas a parameter I will be getting the schema name and as per that schema name I will be executing the query prefixing the schema name something like that

```
select abccode from {schema-name}.tablename ;
```

please advise how can this be achieved with spring boot JPA.

Comment: That's not possible because you are mapping the entities to a specific schema or no schema. But you could check out Hibernates approach to multitenancy https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the entity manager to create a query like this:

```
...

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public someMethod(String databaseName, String schemaName) {
    this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("select abccode from" + databaseName + "." + schemaName + ".tablename");
}
```